# ViewController moving up - iOS

Tags: ios

This following code is to scroll view up. However, it is not shifting up my viewcontoller. I have debugged code and it hits every single line of code , but my view controller. is not shifting up

```
//DownViewController.m

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.hoursTextField) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        taggy=self.hoursTextField.tag;
    }
    if (textField ==self.codeTextField) {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        taggy=self.codeTextField.tag;

    }
    return YES;

}
    - (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        //Assign new frame to your view
        sensorViewController =[[SensorsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SensorsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [sensorViewController setTag:taggy];


    }


//SensorsViewController.m

    -(void)setTag: (int)tag
    {
        if(tag==1)
        {
            a=-80;
            [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,a,1030,768)];
        }
        if(tag==2)
        {
             a=-260;
            [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,a,1030,768)];
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is the frame before the setTag: is called?

Comment: Wait a minute...

You instantiate a viewController, then set the frame before it is displayed. That sounds like a problem.

Comment: How could be solved? How could I access the setTag method without initiate SensorViewController in DownViewController

Comment: Show the viewController first. Then change some values.

Comment: View controllers themselves are invisible -- they don't do any drawing. Perhaps you mean your view controller's view?

Answer (score 0):

Shift the call of `setTag` method inside `viewDidLoad` of `SensorsViewController`.

Comment: How could be solved? How could I access the setTag method without initiate SensorViewController in DownViewController?

Comment: You should create sensorviewcontroller in the videdidload method of DownViewController.

Comment: I did, but it is still not shifting up my SensorviewController setFrame

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a new value to `sensorViewController` every time the keyboard shows. That instance that you just assigned isn't onscreen, so of course the one that is onscreen won't be affected. You should keep a reference to the view controller that's already onscreen, maybe with an IBOutlet if you're using a storyboard or nib file.

Comment: How could be solved? How could I access the setTag method without initiate SensorViewController in DownViewController

Comment: The question is, what do you want? Do you want the `sensorViewController` to first appear when the keyboard shows? Or is it already showing?

Comment: sensorViewController appear first, several free form viewcontrollers added on it. Once of them is downviewcontoller as you can see in my question description

Comment: @ReyGonzales, how could I make this method public?

Comment: Try removing the line that starts with `sensorViewController = ` and see what happens. If you have a valid `sensorViewController` to start with, then it should work.

Comment: then how I could call setTag method from DownViewController class to SensorsViewController class. Should I use appDelegate?

Comment: I removed sensorViewController line and then once I debug, it is not going inside sensorViewController anymore.

Comment: Well then `sensorViewController` must not be a valid object when the keyboard shows. Where else are you assigning `sensorViewController`? Another area of your code, or is it an outlet in Interface Builder perhaps?

Comment: sensorviewcontroller comes when I created a new class with m.h. and xib

Comment: Once I  commented out sensorViewController in DownViewController, and put it into ViewDidLoad () section, it goes into sensorViewController class but, once it hits [self.view setFrame:] , it does affect/shift view controller